# openni_launch problem

Tags: openni-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to use the openni_kinect. There is no errors or warnings when I installed openni_kinect as the instructions in http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect, but when I tried to use openni_launch by typing

roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

in the terminal,

It has many errors as follows:

Found 23 error(s).

ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/metric] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/driver] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/ir/rectify_ir] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/metric_rect] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/register_depth_rgb] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/metric_rect] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/rectify_depth] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/rosout] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/rectify_mono] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth_registered/metric] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_nodelet_manager] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/rectify_color] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link3] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link1] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera_base_link2] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/disparity_depth] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/depth/points] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/disparity_depth_registered] raised an error:
ERROR Communication with [/camera/rgb/debayer] raised an error:
ERROR The following nodes should be connected but aren't:

- /camera/depth/metric_rect->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth/rectify_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link1->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera/register_depth_rgb->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link2->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/disparity_depth_registered->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/driver->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth_registered/metric->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/ir/rectify_ir->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth/metric->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_nodelet_manager->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/rgb/rectify_color->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link1->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/disparity_depth->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera_base_link3->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera/depth/points->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/depth_registered/metric_rect->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link3->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera_base_link2->/camera_nodelet_manager (/tf)
- /camera/rgb/rectify_mono->/rosout (/rosout)
- /camera/rgb/debayer->/rosout (/rosout)

How to solve this problem?

I highly appreciate your time and great help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39852/openni_launch-problem/) by [Lili Meng](https://answers.ros.org/users/2899/lili-meng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 286 on 2012-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need some more info from you... Are you on a turtlebot? Are you using a kinect camera? Is it powered from the turtlebot?

Assuming you have the turtlebot with a kinect: I had some trouble when I plugged the kinect into the USB 2.0 ports. Try it int he USB 3.0. If that doesn't fix it, run this and post the output:

```
lsusb
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-07-27**:
I was under the impression that the Kinect did not work with USB 3.0 at all... Did you possibly mean it the other way around?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-27**:
Nope. I've always used it through USB 3.0

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-07-27**:
Interesting, I don't have USB 3.0 to test it on, but I have seen quite a few posts such as [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/30474/usb-30-kinect/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/openni-dev/f6Y-NAUGU_I) that say otherwise.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-07-27**:
Although [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/9179/kinect-and-usb-30/) post has a comment that says with newer kernels it might be possible.  Regardless, I suppose it is a moot point until the @LiliMeng responds.